# Two ViewPager fragments side by side will not focus EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-viewpager

I've implemented a ViewPager that have different fragments on each page. In Portrait mode, the ViewPager displays a single fragment. In Landscape mode, the ViewPager displays two fragments side by side. I've achieved this by using the getPageWidth() override in the ViewPagerAdapter. Like this:

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    if ((metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density) > 900) {
        return (0.5f);
    }
    return super.getPageWidth(position);
}
```

In both fragments I have EditText fields.

When in Landscape mode and the two fragments are sitting side by side, I can click and give focus to the EditText on the left fragment. When trying to click the EditText on the right fragment, I cannot and get the following warning in my log:

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity /*implements PageLoader*/ {
    MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    DirectionalViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        pager = (DirectionalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(8);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private static final int NUM_ITEMS = 4;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show Frag1
                    return Frag1.newInstance(position, Frag1.class.getSimpleName());
                case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show Frag1 different title
                    return Frag1.newInstance(position, Frag1.class.getSimpleName());
                case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show Frag2
                    return Frag2.newInstance(position, Frag2.class.getSimpleName());
                default:
                    return Frag3.newInstance(position, Frag3.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;

        }

        @Override
        public float getPageWidth(int position) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            if ((metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density) > 900) {
                return (0.5f);
            }
            return super.getPageWidth(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**Frag1.java**, **Frag2.java**, and **Frag3.java**

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static Frag1 newInstance(int page, String title) {
        Frag1 fragmentFirst = new Frag1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }
    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**frag1.xml**, **frag2.xml**, and **frag3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#cc2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_frag1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="txt_frag1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_frag1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="btn_frag1"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_frag1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="ET_FRAG1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Why is it happening and how do I get around it?

Comment: you should hide Keyboard manually and show again when you switch Editext .

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. I tried hiding the keyboard OnFocusChange and show it again when user clicks on the edit text. But the EditText on the right refuses to focus. I even tried to v.requestFocus() in the OnClick event.

Comment: try using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: @UmaAchanta My ViewPager is not within a fragment. It is actually in the MainActivity. Please review code. I'm not exactly sure what you're hinting at.

Comment: have you solved this issue? I have the same issue, no luck so far, not even customViewPager idea with changing populate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After countless hours scouring the internet, I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240063/android-edittext-focus-jumps-to-another-inside-scrollview/22673411#22673411) which explains that this problem is innately a ViewPager problem. Therefore the only way to truly fix it is to modify the ViewPager source itself.

```
void populate(int newCurrentItem) {

    // ... CODES OMITTED

    if (hasFocus()) {
        View currentFocused = findFocus();
        ItemInfo ii = currentFocused != null ? infoForAnyChild(currentFocused) : null;
        if (ii == null || !infoIsOnScreen(ii)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                ii = infoForChild(child);
                if (ii != null && infoIsOnScreen(ii)) {
                    if (child.requestFocus(FOCUS_FORWARD)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean infoIsOnScreen(ItemInfo info) {
    float curItemOffset = mCurItem * info.widthFactor;  // find the offset value for curr item
    float offsetUpperBound = curItemOffset + 1;         // +1 to get the upper bound offset value
    if ((info.offset >= curItemOffset) && (info.offset < offsetUpperBound))
        return true; // curr item offset value is within bound, hence it is on the screen
    return false;
}
```

Please up-vote this or the other SO answer if you find this useful, because it was really hard to dig it up due to the unpopularity of this problem. Although I don't understand why that would be considering ViewPager is itself popular, so surely people have used EditText before (perhaps just not many use them in multiple pages on the same screen)